# Handle exception in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I have added $exceptionHandler

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', function () {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            alert(exception + cause);
        };
    });
```

Add I have a service

```
SomeService.save({
                    someaction : action,
                }, function(result) {
                   console.log(result)
                }
            )
```

Java method that sets exception message

```
   @ExceptionHandler(IllegalStateException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleRequest(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

If this service throws exception $exceptionHandler catches the exception but exception message says unexpected token instead of the error message I am setting in my java method.